# Taskbar cut off when using VGA on second monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, vga

I recently got a second monitor for my setup. Only having one HDMI port on my computer, I use my main display with HDMI and my second display with VGA.

Not always but usually when I log into windows, the taskbar is cut off, and the picture is all blurry. Turning off and on the monitor fixes the issue until the next time I log in.

Why does it do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be related to graphics card driver or display resolution. Try below:

1. Update the driver
2. Set your graphics driver to display the native resolution of the monitor. If you don’t know which one it is, search for the model specs.
3. Locate the physical buttons on the monitor and navigate the menus to find “auto setup”, “auto calibration”, “auto image” or “auto adjustment”.
4. Adjust the resolution manually in display settings
5. Press Windows key+Ctrl+Shift+B, which basically resets your graphics card driver.Your screens will flash black then come right.

Comment: 1. The driver is up to date

2. It is displaying at the native resolution

3. The auto adjustment does nothing

4. When I change it, it does not fill up the whole screen, but if I let it revert I can see the taskbar
5. this does fix it, but its a hassle to have to do that every time, better than turning it on and off though